# Always show all tabs

Tags: feature-request, bountied-tab

When you're on the `featured` tab and click on a tag so that you navigate to the **tagged questions** view and there are no related questions with active bounties, you'll end up on a page with this message:

[image]

What I find highly confusing however is that the tab header is not displayed in such cases. I'd like to propose to always show the tabs for the sake of clarity and consistency.

Comment: @Vogel612 you need to pass `sort` instead of `tab`: stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic?sort=featured

Comment: please clarify what you mean by "navigate to a tag". when i click featured and then [tag:asp-classic] i end up on the "newest asp-classic questions". yea i just found out myself..

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/szKzdJg.png, I had to change the URL manually since all of my favourite tags have featured questions.

Comment: Thanks @Vogel612, I've updated my question